# How to execute "sudo nvm"?

Tags: node.js, shell, unix, terminal, nvm

On my Mac, I want to migrate some packages that require su rights to another node version.

I used homebrew to install nvm and now I need to execute sudo nvm or `--reinstall-packages` will fail.

```
me@MacBook:~$ sudo nvm
sudo: nvm: command not found
me@MacBook:~$ sudo node -v
v5.4.1
me@MacBook:~$ sudo npm -v
3.3.12
me@MacBook:~$ nvm ls
->       v5.4.1
         v9.6.1
         system
default -> 5.4.1 (-> v5.4.1)
node -> stable (-> v9.6.1) (default)
stable -> 9.6 (-> v9.6.1) (default)
iojs -> N/A (default)
lts/* -> lts/carbon (-> N/A)
lts/argon -> v4.8.7 (-> N/A)
lts/boron -> v6.13.0 (-> N/A)
lts/carbon -> v8.9.4 (-> N/A)
```

I think the command cannot be found, because sudo is looking in different paths. I've found nvm.sh in `/usr/local/opt/nvm`, however:

```
sudo /usr/local/opt/nvm/nvm.sh ls
```

returns nothing.

Even

```
/usr/local/opt/nvm/nvm.sh ls
```

returns nothing, so I suspect this is the wrong shell script.

How can I call nvm with sudo, explicitly?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Consider defining a shell function wrapper:

```
nvmsudo() { sudo bash -lic '. /usr/local/opt/nvm/nvm.sh && nvm "$@"' _ "$@"; }
```

...thereafter:

```
nvmsudo --version
```

...or...

```
nvmsudo install 5.4.1 --reinstall-packages-from=9.6.1
```

---

To explain the above logic:

- Using the `-l` and `-i` arguments to bash ensure that dotfiles for the target user (in this case `root`) are run, which appears to be necessary for `nvm`'s correct operation.
- `bash -c`'s immediate next argument must be a script. The arguments following that become `$0`, `$1`, etc. in the context where the script is executed.
- `"$@"` in the function context refers to the full set of arguments to the function.
- `"$@"` in the `bash -c` script's context refers to the full set of arguments (starting at `$1`, so skipping the `_`) passed to the shell after the `-c`.

Comment: Thanks, but using `nvmsudo --version` returns `_: /opt/local/opt/nvm/nvm.sh: No such file or directory`, what do you mean by saying "skipping the `_`"?

Comment: Replace the filename to actually be correct, of course. "Skipping the `_`" means that because the `_` becomes `$0` (which is, as you notice, used in error messages as the name of the script), it isn't included in `"$@"`. I suppose you might replace `_` with `nvmsudo`, so it would be `nvmsudo: ...` on an error message from the shell, if you were so inclined; that said, `_` is conventional as a placeholder, so using that string has value for readability.

Comment: my bad, thanks for correcting the answer, however it still seems to fail parsing the arguments, because the last command returns `If --reinstall-packages-from is provided, it must point to an installed version of node.`.

Comment: Change it from `bash -c` to `bash -xc` and you'll see what it runs, so you can see for yourself whether the command-line arguments are correctly passed through. More likely arguments are all passed through correctly, but the script invoked is depending on environment variables having values that aren't set in non-login shells.

Comment: If it needs to be treated as an interactive login shell to source the pertinent dotfiles, then you might want something like `bash -lic` instead, but we're getting into making assumptions about the details of how your machine is configured at this point.

Comment: @modiX, ...if you *can* generate anything indicating that this is an issue with arguments being passed through correctly, as opposed to a configuration-centric issue with the application after it's properly invoked, I'll be most interested.

Comment: Thank you so much, using `-lic` worked. So having an interactive login shell command seems to be required for `nvm` to run as su. This is clearly a better solution now, since it does not require me to login as su in the terminal. Please edit your answer to match this case and I can accept your answer.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback; folded that into the answer.

Comment: "If --reinstall-packages-from is provided, it must point to an installed version of node." I get this as answer.

Comment: @another, the same debugging steps discussed earlier in this comment thread apply.

Answer (score 0):

Try with below command:-

```
sudo -u <username> /usr/local/opt/nvm/nvm.sh
```

Do not use `ls` first, if it works then only try with `ls`

Comment: `sudo -u me nvm` (used my actual username ofc) resulted in the same error `sudo: nvm: command not found`. Also, I tried to call nvm.sh without argument like you did, it returns nothing. I still believe this is the wrong shell file ...

Comment: Open the shell file and check the logic in it instead of hit and try.

Comment: It's the actual source of nvm. https://pastebin.com/Fj6XE3eZ It reach nvm_process_parameters, idk why it does not work. I also tried to `cd /usr/local/opt/nvm/` and `./nvm.sh`, directly.

Comment: What error you are getting while you run like `./nvm.sh`?

Comment: put some `echo` statement inside `nvm.sh` and check whether those echo statement are prints or not like `echo "teat 1"`

Comment: I've added some echo's. It enters `nvm_process_parameters`, `nvm_supports_source_options` is true, it enters the `nvm_auto` function. The function cares only for "install" and "use" arguments, yet `sudo ./nvm.sh install 5.4.1 --reinstall-packages-from=9.6.1` does nothing. This file seems to be a wrapper, because it calls `nvm` by itself (i.e. line 3510), it's not? I think I'm in the wrong place ...

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, even when this is not a beautiful solution in my opinion.

I had a misunderstanding, suspecting `nvm.sh` gets called on `nvm`, directly. In fact, `nvm.sh` contains several shell functions that are loaded in the user shell environment, but not in the root shell environment.

First, [I enabled the root user](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204012) and logged it in at the terminal. Then I had to `source` the contents of the `nvm.sh` to define the functions at the su environment. Then I could run the command and the su found it:

```
me@MacBook:~$ su
Password:
root@MacBook:/Users/me$ source /usr/local/opt/nvm/nvm.sh
root@MacBook:/Users/me$ nvm --version
0.33.8
```

Works!

Comment: What is the 0.33.8 version? and how to change it?, it differs from the output from node  `node -v`

Comment: It's the version of nvm (node version manager), not node itself.