# How to migrate a global cordova package (acorn-node) to an older node version with NVM?

Tags: node.js, cordova, unix, migration, nvm

On my MacBook I'm trying to migrate several global node packages (including cordova) from the latest node version 9.6.1 to an older node version 5.4.1.

Terminal command:

```
marty@MettBook:~$ nvm install 5.4.1 --reinstall-packages-from=9.6.1
```

Output:

```
v5.4.1 is already installed.
Now using node v5.4.1 (npm v3.3.12)
Reinstalling global packages from v9.6.1...
npm WARN deprecated bower@1.7.2: ...psst! Your project can stop working at any moment because its dependencies can change. Prevent this by migrating to Yarn: https://bower.io/blog/2017/how-to-migrate-away-from-bower/
npm WARN deprecated node-uuid@1.4.8: Use uuid module instead
npm WARN deprecated gulp-util@3.0.8: gulp-util is deprecated - replace it, following the guidelines at https://medium.com/gulpjs/gulp-util-ca3b1f9f9ac5
npm WARN deprecated graceful-fs@3.0.11: please upgrade to graceful-fs 4 for compatibility with current and future versions of Node.js
npm WARN deprecated minimatch@2.0.10: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue
npm WARN deprecated minimatch@0.2.14: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue
npm WARN deprecated graceful-fs@1.2.3: please upgrade to graceful-fs 4 for compatibility with current and future versions of Node.js
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /Users/marty/.nvm/versions/node/v9.6.1/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/acorn-node/node_modules
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /Users/marty/.nvm/versions/node/v9.6.1/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/detective/node_modules

/Users/marty/.nvm/versions/node/v9.6.1/lib
├── bower@1.7.2 
├─┬ cordova@6.5.0 
│ ├─┬ cordova-lib@6.5.0
│ │ └─┬ cordova-js@4.2.1
│ │   └─┬ browserify@13.3.0
│ │     ├─┬ module-deps@4.1.1
│ │     │ └─┬ detective@4.7.1
│ │     │   └── acorn@5.5.1 
│ │     ├── readable-stream@2.3.5 
│ │     └─┬ syntax-error@1.4.0
│ │       └─┬ acorn-node@1.3.0
│ │         └── acorn@5.5.1 
│ └─┬ insight@0.8.4
│   └─┬ request@2.83.0
│     └── safe-buffer@5.1.1 
└─┬ gulp@3.9.1 
  └─┬ gulp-util@3.0.8
    └─┬ through2@2.0.3
      └─┬ readable-stream@2.3.5 
        ├── safe-buffer@5.1.1 
        └─┬ string_decoder@1.0.3
          └── safe-buffer@5.1.1
```

Error output:

```
npm ERR! Darwin 17.4.0
npm ERR! argv "/Users/marty/.nvm/versions/node/v5.4.1/bin/node" "/Users/marty/.nvm/versions/node/v5.4.1/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "--quiet" "bower@1.7.2" "cordova@6.5.0" "gulp@3.9.1"
npm ERR! node v5.4.1
npm ERR! npm  v3.3.12
npm ERR! path /Users/marty/.nvm/versions/node/v9.6.1/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/acorn-node/node_modules
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! syscall access

npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/Users/marty/.nvm/versions/node/v9.6.1/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/acorn-node/node_modules'
npm ERR!     at Error (native)
npm ERR!  { [Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/Users/marty/.nvm/versions/node/v9.6.1/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/acorn-node/node_modules']
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'access',
npm ERR!   path: '/Users/marty/.nvm/versions/node/v9.6.1/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/acorn-node/node_modules' }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /usr/local/Cellar/nvm/0.33.8/npm-debug.log
Linking global packages from v9.6.1...
```

Here is my full npm-debug.log: https://www.dropbox.com/s/a206meg3nbhfoc2/npm-debug_1.log?dl=0

I tried to solve it by giving everyone full permissions on this path:

```
sudo chmod 777 /Users/marty/.nvm/versions/node/v9.6.1/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/detective/node_modules/acorn
```

This did not help, the error persists.

Unfortunately, [I cannot even use `sudo` with `nvm`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49130176/how-to-execute-sudo-nvm). What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to [How to execute "sudo nvm"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49130176/how-to-execute-sudo-nvm), so I could bypass this issue by executing this task as super user.